# WhatsApp for Ubuntu Phone?

Tags: ubuntu-touch, whatsapp

Does someone know if there already is a WhatsApp Version for Ubuntu Phone?
I decided to install Ubuntu on my Android, but I don't want to use my phone without WhatsApp.

Comment: https://answers.launchpad.net/whosthere/+question/231055

Comment: No, there isnt at the moment. The opensource version was abandoned because of complexity with Whatapp's API

Comment: You are going to have to get WhatsApp to port their app to Ubuntu. Outside of that, you are not going to be able to use WhatsApp on any system they do not support.

Comment: I think Whatsapp wants to rig the game by not creating a client for Ubuntu phone. They can keep working on other platforms, where there is no security or privacy, and end of the day, that's the target of whatsapp, not open-source, not Ubuntu...

Answer (score 6):

There is currently (October 30th, 2013) no official Whatsapp client for Ubuntu One.

There were some non-official clients that were either [web-based](http://whatsapp.filshmedia.net/) or simple [to](https://code.google.com/p/whatsapp-desktop-client/) [port](http://openwhatsapp.org/about/) but all that I knew have been discontinued. While the Whatsapp protocol looks easy to implement it changes too often, breaking non-official clients until the changes are reverse engineered.

Answer (score 2):

I tried LoquiIM for Ubuntu Phone and it is working (with a few limitations in this first release):
https://open.uappexplorer.com/app/com.ubuntu.loqui.im.loqui

Comment: This is really awesome!

Answer (score 1):

I just installed whatsapp from the standard Software Download Feature on my Nexus 4 running Ubuntu-Touch. So yes, it works.

Answer (score 1):

I too have been watching this space for an official release of WhatsApp on Ubuntu Touch, however there is currently not one. The last post that I read about this stated that there was not going to be one. This is a shame as this is one of the IM's that people have come to expect from their smartphones. Yes we have Telegram, which is moving along nice. However, what is the point in having that when the rest of your friends all use WhatsApp. The web versions are an option and one that I have used before. However, when the phone powers down, you have to scan the code again to log in. I suspect one answer is do not let your phone power down and you will always be able to use it. Hopefully, there will be an app out soon as like I say, this is one of them must have apps for most users. Users are not suddenly going to swap from WHatsApp to Telegram, WhatsApp is too embedded in smartphone users minds now.