# voice encryption in UbuntoTouch

Tags: ubuntu-touch

I want a phone to phone voice encryption on UbuntuTouch and Nexus 5. Is there any way to do that? 
I have changed the Nexus 5 Android with UbuntuTouch

Comment: Sorry...  I wish there was one as I'd use it too!  **;-)**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, today there is only secure messaging using Telegram (installed by default on my BQ Aquaris Ubuntu Touch phone) and other similar applications, but there are no secure voice clients like [WhatsApp](https://askubuntu.com/questions/368360/whatsapp-for-ubuntu-phone), Viber, ... as qTox has been discontinued...

### :-(